# Adding metadata informations with ffmpeg

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, metadata

I am trying to read and most important to write metadata into file using ffmpeg. But I am getting sigseg.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    av_register_all();

    AVFormatContext* ctx;
    std::string path("/home/stefan/test_track.mp3");

    ctx = avformat_alloc_context();

    if (avformat_open_input(&ctx, path.c_str(), 0, 0) < 0)
        std::cout << "error1" << std::endl;

    if (avformat_find_stream_info(ctx, 0) < 0)
        std::cout << "error2" << std::endl;

    AVDictionaryEntry *tag = nullptr;
    tag = av_dict_get(ctx->metadata, "artist", tag, AV_DICT_IGNORE_SUFFIX);
    std::cout << tag->key << " : " << tag->value << std::endl;

    av_dict_set(&ctx->metadata, "TPFL", "testtest", 0);

    std::cout << "test!" << std::endl;
    int status = avformat_write_header(ctx, &ctx->metadata);

    if(status == 0)
        std::cout << "test1" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I also tried to make a entire copy of AVDictionary and than saving it with new addition of field I want to save. But still sigseg.

What am I missing?

Comment: Which line you get SIGSEG?

Comment: write_header function...

Comment: avformat_write_header write to output context. Here you passed an input context to it.
Can you show a backtrace?

Comment: Isnt that same thing? I open context, make changes and than write to? How I can check if this is open context or output? And how to convert it? Regarding backtrace, how I can activate it in ffmpeg lib? All I get is Segmentation Fault.

Comment: No, they aren't the same thing, you must have an `AVFormatContext` initialized with `avformat_init_output`. https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.2/group__lavf__encoding.html#ga169cfa28508e22e138c5b99be8517ea4

Comment: You can build ffmpeg with debuging enabled, or use the debug build link libraries to get a stack trace.

Comment: I will test it and report if I succeeded :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another `AVFormatContext` to write your output.

In your example, just add some meta data and copy the codec, so the muxing steps for ffmpeg library is

1. create the desired output format context, `avformat_alloc_output_context2`
2. add streams to the output format context, `avformat_new_stream`
3. add some custom meta data and write header
4. use `av_write_frame` to write the encoded data
5. write trailer

Below is a workable example with small modification of your code.

```
#include <iostream>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include <libavformat/avformat.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus 
}
#endif


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    av_register_all();
    avcodec_register_all();

    AVFormatContext* ctx;
    std::string path("./input.mp3");

    ctx = avformat_alloc_context();

    if (avformat_open_input(&ctx, path.c_str(), 0, 0) < 0)
        std::cout << "error1" << std::endl;

    if (avformat_find_stream_info(ctx, 0) < 0)
        std::cout << "error2" << std::endl;

    AVDictionaryEntry *tag = nullptr;
    tag = av_dict_get(ctx->metadata, "artist", tag, AV_DICT_IGNORE_SUFFIX);
    std::cout << tag->key << " : " << tag->value << std::endl;

    av_dict_set(&ctx->metadata, "TPFL", "testtest", 0);

    std::cout << "test!" << std::endl;

    int status;

    AVFormatContext* ofmt_ctx;
    AVOutputFormat* ofmt = av_guess_format("mp3", "./out.mp3", NULL);
    status = avformat_alloc_output_context2(&ofmt_ctx, ofmt, "mp3", "./out.mp3");
    if (status < 0) {
        std::cerr << "could not allocate output format" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    int audio_stream_index = 0;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        if (ctx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            audio_stream_index = i;
            const AVCodec *c = avcodec_find_encoder(ctx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_id);
            if (c) {
                AVStream *ostream = avformat_new_stream(ofmt_ctx, c);
                avcodec_parameters_copy(ostream->codecpar, ctx->streams[i]->codecpar);
                ostream->codecpar->codec_tag = 0;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    av_dict_set(&ofmt_ctx->metadata, "TPFL", "testtest", 0);

    av_dump_format(ofmt_ctx, 0, "./out.mp3", 1);

    if (!(ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        avio_open(&ofmt_ctx->pb, "./out.mp3", AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
    }

    if (avformat_init_output(ofmt_ctx, NULL) == AVSTREAM_INIT_IN_WRITE_HEADER) {
        status = avformat_write_header(ofmt_ctx, NULL);
    }

    AVPacket *pkt = av_packet_alloc();
    av_init_packet(pkt);
    pkt->data = NULL;
    pkt->size = 0;

    while (av_read_frame(ctx, pkt) == 0) {
        if (pkt->stream_index == audio_stream_index) {
            // this is optional, we are copying the stream
            av_packet_rescale_ts(pkt, ctx->streams[audio_stream_index]->time_base,
                                 ofmt_ctx->streams[audio_stream_index]->time_base);
            av_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, pkt);
        }
    }

    av_packet_free(&pkt);

    av_write_trailer(ofmt_ctx);

    avformat_close_input(&ctx);
    avformat_free_context(ofmt_ctx);
    avformat_free_context(ctx);

    if(status == 0)
        std::cout << "test1" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

After done, you can use `ffprobe output.mp3` to check the written meta data.

```
Input #0, mp3, from 'out.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TPFL            : testtest
    encoder         : Lavf57.75.100
  Duration: 00:00:08.75, start: 0.011995, bitrate: 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavf
```

Comment: There is no way to do this without creating new file? No way to just modify metadata on existing one?

Comment: As far as I know, you have to create a new file to hold the modified metadata.

Comment: can the input file name be used for output as well? so that new file is not created